# Create Thumb in MouseDown and have it drag?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a WPF Thumb object inside of a MouseDown event handler. As long as the user holds the mouse down, they should be able to drag the Thumb object. However, the mouse event is not forwarded to my new Thumb object. In fact, I doubt the object is actually created before the currently executing thread has a reprieve. How can I start the Thumb in drag mode? If I dispatch some code at Input priority, what can I do to programmatically begin the drag operation on the Thumb object?

Comment: As far as I know thumbs, they would detect the drag operation themselves, so the solution could be to have the thumb invisibly in place all the time (covering all the "draggable" client area), and only to provide visual feedback when it is dragged. You could then use the thumb's drag and drop events to detect that condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of lack of code I assume you really mean *"creating a WPF Thumb object inside of a MouseDown event handler"*. Does below suffice?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas Name="RootCanvas" Background="White"/>
</Window>
```

---

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RootCanvas.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
        {
            Thumb thumb = new Thumb();
            thumb.Width = thumb.Height = 35;
            thumb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

            Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, e.GetPosition((Canvas)s).X - thumb.Width / 2);
            Canvas.SetTop(thumb, e.GetPosition((Canvas)s).Y - thumb.Height / 2);

            thumb.DragDelta += (d, r) =>
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft((UIElement)d, Canvas.GetLeft((UIElement)d) + r.HorizontalChange);
                Canvas.SetTop((UIElement)d, Canvas.GetTop((UIElement)d) + r.VerticalChange);
            };

            ((Canvas)s).Children.Add(thumb);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() => thumb.RaiseEvent(e)));
        };
    }
```

[EDIT]

This is 'almost' working example. For some reason upon first `thumb.DragDelta`, values of `r.HorizontalChange` and `r.VerticalChange` are not those of mouse delta, but mouse delta minus current thumb position, which has a net effect of placing thumb at (0,0) ish.

[EDIT2]

Updated to working.

Comment: I appreciate you posting example code. The tricky thing that I'm looking to solve, though, is the ability to drag that Thumb object without having to click a second time.

Comment: Can't you add the current location of the thumb position to `r.HorizontalChange` and `r.VerticalChange` at the first time, in order to get the actual `thumb.DragDelta` ?

Comment: you could, but how do you determine that it's the first time?

Comment: I made it work by changing the last line to this: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() => thumb.RaiseEvent(e)));`

Comment: Interesting, I wonder what in the pipeline causes this. I have a feeling it's something to do with `DragDelta` delegate being created when `Canvas` doesn't know the position of `Thumb` yet. Anyway, collective work always pays off :)

Answer (score 0):

I improved the code from *@StaWho*, because that will behave abnormally when putting the RootCanvas into a scrollViewer.

```
RootCanvas.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
{
    Thumb thumb = new Thumb();
    thumb.Width = thumb.Height = 35;
    thumb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, e.GetPosition((Canvas)s).X - thumb.Width / 2);
    Canvas.SetTop(thumb, e.GetPosition((Canvas)s).Y - thumb.Height / 2);

    thumb.DragDelta += (d, r) =>
    {
        var mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(RootCanvas);
        Canvas.SetLeft((UIElement)d, mousePosition.X);
        Canvas.SetTop((UIElement)d, mousePosition.Y);
    };

    ((Canvas)s).Children.Add(thumb);
    thumb.RaiseEvent(e);
};
```